# How can I relate Model A to either Model B OR Model C in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, database-schema, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4's Eloquent to make three different models: a User model, an Agent model, and a Performer model. Any user can sign up as a normal user, or can pay to become an Agent OR a Performer. Because both Agents and Performers have special profiles, I've created separate tables for both Performers and Agents that will contain their profiles, and just a user "type" in the Users table, which indicates whether they're a normal user, a Performer, or an Agent.

This means that the User model will have a has_one relationship with both Performer and Agent. Because a user will only ever be one of those, I'm wondering if it's possible to have the User model only relate to one of those (or none) depending on what type the user is?

I have a strong feeling that I'm going about this the wrong way. Should I relate the User model to both and just check before I use the relationships (which seemed obvious at first, but not quite the right approach either)? Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: I specified above that the user might not be either of those but just a normal user, however it seems I was too vague: so, if a user hasn't paid to become either an agent or a performer, they'll just be a normal user. Is the best strategy in that case to just manually fill in "user" for the `userable_type` column and check to make sure it's not equal to "user" before I do `$user->userable`?

Comment: Check out polymorphic relations.  It's probably exactly what you need and you already have yourself setup for it.  Basically you'd find your user, call the relation, and it would return an instance of either an Agent or Performer.  http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Schema::create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('username');
    $table->string('imageable_type');  // Will be a string of the class name Agent or Performer
    $table->string('imageable_id');    // Will be the ID of the Agent or Performer.
});

class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Agent extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('User', 'imageable');
    }
}

class Performer extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('User', 'imageable');
    }
}

$user = User::find(1);
$type = $user->imageable;  // Type will be either an instance of Agent or Performer

if($type instanceof Agent)
{
    // Do agent stuff
} else {
    // Do performer stuff
}
```

Comment: Hah! I'm using polymorphic for other models, but I didn't even think about it for this one. That was silly of me. Thanks very much!

Comment: Ahh, OK I've got a question about your answer. It works if the user is either an Agent or a Performer, but what if the user is just a normal user? A user doesn't have to be either of those two special user types.

Comment: You could likely morph the user table into itself.  I haven't tested doing that, but I am assuming it should work fine.